# Search and Download Apk in an app Android

Tags: android, download, google-play, apk

My question is just one sentence: How can i download another apk from market in an my own written application ?

I used :

```
AsyncTask(){

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
                session.login("**@gmail.com","**");
                session.getContext().setAndroidId("dead00beef");

                String query = "maps";
                AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setQuery(query)
                        .setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10)
                        .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
                        .build();

                session.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                session.flush();
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
```

But google bans my connection and send an email: Someone tried to access your app market account. :D

Any ideas ?

Comment: I answered this before somewhere, can't find it though.. Anyway, this is _not_ a good idea, although you can do it with some hacks.

Comment: can you give some advices how to do ? i really need that .